# Where do Vedas state that Destiny is the nature of Time?

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva-purana, time

Shiva Purana Kailasha Samhita chapter 13 (13.29-30) states;

> मायां तु प्रकृतिं विद्यादिति माया श्रुतीरिता ।
>   तज्जान्येतानि तत्त्वानि श्रुत्युक्तानि न संशय ।।29
>  
>   **It has been propounded in the Vedas that Maya is same as Prakirti.** The principles as mentioned in Srutis are born of that.
>   
>   **कालस्वभावो नियतिरिति च श्रुतिरब्रवित्**।
>   एतत्पञ्चकमेवास्य पञ्चकञ्चक्रमुच्यते ।।30
>  
>   **The Vedas also declare that the destiny is the nature of Kãla (Time).** This set of five is called wheel of five.

The first quote mentioned there can be found in the Svetasvatara Upanishad 4.10 which states:

> मायां तु प्रकृतिं विद्यान्मायिनं च महेश्वरम् ।
>   तस्यवयवभूतैस्तु व्याप्तं सर्वमिदं जगत् ॥ १०॥
>  
>   **Know, then, that Prakriti is Maya** and Maheswara is the Lord of maya. The whole universe is filled with objects which are parts of His being.

But from where is the second quote from?
ie. **Where do Vedas mention as destiny is the nature of Time?** ie. From where is the Shiva Purana quoting that quote of 'kãlaswabhãvo niyati' ?